# Is there any UNIX way to create a figure of a directory structure?

Tags: unix

I want to generate a simple figure (something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHs83.gif)) with sub directory names, file names in a directory. Is there any easiest way in `*nix` to do this?

I often need to submit all my analysis results to core biologists, I feel that it would be easy for them to navigate to the files & figures they need, if I provide this kind of figure also.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You might find `tree` helpful...

http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/

Comment: Thanks Stuart. This helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [tree command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree).

It will display a tree like structure for a directory.

```
tree
.
└── foo
    ├── bar
    │   └── test
    ├── bar2
    │   └── test
    └── test
```

Comment: `tree` comes from Linux, not Unix, though.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. But the OP was asking for a *nix solution. So tree should be ok.

Comment: Thank you very much cb0. Is there anyway to convert the output from `tree` to `.jpg` or `.png` or `.pdf`?

Comment: Found [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/647805/how-to-print-the-output-of-tree-to-pdf-without-losing-the-color) to make a pdf. Its really cool.

Comment: Glad I could help and glad you find a way for the pdf problem. If my answer helped you, please accept it :)